# How to transform these lines using captured groups?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to use `sed` to transform a bunch of lines of text in a file that look like this:

```
{ Interop.SecurityStatus.AlgorithmMismatch, SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.AlgorithmMismatch },
{ Interop.SecurityStatus.BadBinding, SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.BadBinding },
{ Interop.SecurityStatus.BufferNotEnough, SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.BufferNotEnough },
{ Interop.SecurityStatus.CannotInstall, SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.CannotInstall },
```

to this:

```
[Interop.SecurityStatus.AlgorithmMismatch] = SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.AlgorithmMismatch,
[Interop.SecurityStatus.BadBinding] = SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.BadBinding,
[Interop.SecurityStatus.BufferNotEnough] = SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.BufferNotEnough,
[Interop.SecurityStatus.CannotInstall] = SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.CannotInstall,
```

This is what I've tried to accomplish this thus far, using my rusty regexp knowledge:

```
$ sed -i 's/{ (.*), (.*) }/\[\1\] = \2/g' file_name
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working, as I get back this error from my terminal:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, since as far as I can see I have 2 parentheses (and therefore 2 captured groups). Can someone explain to me why `sed` is giving back this error, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default, and as per the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), `sed` uses *basic* regular expressions (BREs)**, in which `(` and `)` are *ordinary* characters and therefore must be `\`-quoted to act as *metacharacters* in order to create capture groups they way you intend (note, however, that `{` and `}` are *also* treated as ordinary characters, which you *do* want):

```
sed -i 's/{ \(.*\), \(.*\) }/\[\1\] = \2/g' file_name
```

However, given that you're already using *nonstandard* option `-i`, you may as well **make your life easier by activating support for *extended* regular expressions (EREs) with GNU `sed`'s nonstandard `-r` option**; while you don't gain much from using EREs in this particular case, they will generally function much more like you would expect them to (as known from other languages):

```
sed -i -r 's/\{ (.*), (.*) \}/\[\1\] = \2/g' file_name
```

`(` and `)` now function they way you expected, but note that it is now `{` and `}` that need to be `\`-quoted in order to be treated as *literals*, because in the context of EREs they are metacharacters used in quantifiers (such as `{1,2}`).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative answer! Worked like a charm :)